# Trying to install Theos

Tags: jailbreak, cydia, theos

I'm trying to install Theos on my iMac using the instructions from [HERE](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started).

It seems to have installed correctly, but when I try to set up a new project in terminal using:
**$THEOS/bin/nic.pl**

It says:
**-bash: /bin/nic.pl: No such file or directory**

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You should unhide your OSX hidden files using this command through TERMINAL :

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE; killall Finder
```

Then open .bash_profile under your USERNAME folder

[edit]
if .bash_profile doesn't existe
Open TERMINAL then write

touch .bash_profile

Then

open -a TextEdit.app .bash_profile

Then add this line inside

```
export THEOS=/opt/theos
```

Good luck

Comment: I used that terminal command and now all of my hidden files show. But they are all grayed out and I do not see the file .bash_profile in my user home folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the guide of iphonedevwiki you should have all that you need to use theos. The correct way to call `nic.pl` should be:

`sudo su`

`/opt/theos/bin/nic.pl`

Comment: OP's method is the correct way. `$THEOS/bin/nic.pl` is a platform independent way to use nic.pl as `$THEOS` varies depending on which operating system you use Theos. Furthermore, using root privileges while executing nic.pl will result in files being owned by root, not the regular user.